# External API Call Using Express

Tags: api, express, require

I'm trying to call a College Score Card API using Express and Request. When I search for a specific school, I receive results from several schools, but not the school I searched for. Here is part of my code:

```
var fields = '_fields=school.name,2013.aid.median_debt.completers.overall,2013.repayment.1_yr_repayment.completers,2013.earnings.10_yrs_after_entry.working_not_enrolled.mean_earnings&page=100';

var requestUrl = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?api_key=' + apiKey + '&' + fields;



module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/school', function(req, res, next) {
        request(requestUrl, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(json); 
            } else {
                console.log("There was an error: ") + response.statusCode;
                console.log(body);
            }
        });
    })
};
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/school" method="GET"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="school_name" value="" id="enter_text"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="text-enter- button">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: html:
    <form action="/school" method="GET">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="school_name" 
                value="" id="enter_text">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="text-enter-
                 button">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: Added the form code to your question using the "edit" link and fixed your formatting.  Please learn how to properly format your code here to make it easy to read.

Comment: What is `requestUrl` and where does it come from?  Right now, it doesn't appear you're using the form values at all in your request and it appears that what results you get will be entirely dependent upon what `requestUrl` is.  So, basically you're not showing us the most important part of the code.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'm new to coding, and this was my first time asking a question.

Comment: How is the school name supposed to be incorporated into the `requestUrl`?  I can help you get it from the form to the URL, but I need to know what it's supposed to look like in the URL.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/school?school_name=pepperdine

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed.  I wrote an answer using that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to incorporate the school name into the URL.  From your form that is set for `method=GET`, the name will come in `req.query.school_name`.  So, instead of just sending the request to `requestUrl`, you send it to:

```
requestUrl + "&school_name=" + req.query.school_name
```

which will add this onto the end of the URL:

```
&school_name=Pepperdine
```

Or, put into your code, it would look like this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/school', function(req, res, next) {
        request(requestUrl + "&school_name=" + req.query.school_name, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(json); 
                res.send(...);    // send some response here
            } else {
                console.log("There was an error: ") + response.statusCode;
                console.log(body);
                res.send(...)     // send some response here
            }
        });
    })
};
```

Comment: I tried this, and I receive a message saying 'Waiting for local host...', and nothing happens.

Comment: @user8767190 - Did you actually fill in `res.send()` to return some content?  
 You have to send a response to the request or the browser just sits and waits forever (eventually timing out).  Did your `console.log()` statements on the server show a result?

Comment: It works now. I needed to use school.name. Thanks for your help!